# What's the connection between exceptional divisor and projectivized tangent space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is one homework problem and hence I want some hint but not a whole answer.

Let $P$ be a projective space and $X\subset P$ be a non-singular variety.
Prove that the collection $L_p$ of lines contained in $X$ that pass through $p$ defines a **closed subset** of the projectivized tangent space $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$.

In other word, we want to show that such defined $L_p$ defines a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$:$$L_p = \{l:p\in l\subset X, l\text{ is a 1-dimensional linear subspace in P}\}.$$

I cannot see the connection between $L_p$ and $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$. Please try to explain the connection using elementary knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: Intuitively, in the case of $P = X$, we have $L_p$ can be identified with $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$. But even in this case, I don't know how to prove the identification. Please help:-(

Comment: The centered definition of $L_p$ seems to be missing reference to $X$. Do you know how to justify writing $L_p \subseteq \mathbb{P}(T_pX)$ in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, I've modified it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see how a line through $P$, lying in $X$, gives a tangent direction to $X$ at $P$?  This is the first step, and if you don't see it right away, try drawing a picture of a surface with a line lying on it (e.g. a quadric in space), and then see if you see it.

Added: As discussed in comments (assuming that we are working with closed points of varieties over an alg. closed field $k$), if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism and $x \in X$, we get an induced morphism $f_*: T_x X \to T_y Y.$

Now apply this with the source $X$ being a line $L$ through $p$ and lying on $X$, the target $Y$ being $X$, and $f$ being the inclusion $L \subset Y$.  And, course, set $x = y = p$.

Then we get a morphism  $T_p L \to T_p X.$

(a) Show that when $f$ is a closed immersion, the morphism $f_*$ is an embedding.
In particular, in our case, we see that $T_pL$ embeds into $T_p X$.

(b) What is $T_pL$?

(c) Put (a) and (b) together to make substantial progress on your question.

Comment: But the definition of tangent space is the dual space of a cotangent space. I don't know how to rigorously prove the correspondence between line $l$ and tangent direction.

Comment: Try proving the tangent spaces have the correct functoriality: if $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of varieties (or schemes, for that matter) and $x$ is a point of $X$, and $y = f(x)$, then there is a canonical induced morphism $f_* : T_x X \to \kappa(x) \otimes_{\kappa(y)} T_y Y$ on Zariski tangent spaces.

Comment: Also: you are technically correct in your comment about the definition, although there is no need to mention cotangent spaces either; you could just say it is the dual of $m_x/m_x^2$.   But a key step in learning to work with these ideas (tangents spaces, bundled, divisors) in (the algebraic approach to) algebraic geometry is to see how to move from the technical definitions to the geometric intuitions they are meant to capture.  Things like induced morphisms of the kind described in my previous comment are one of the tools you can use for doing this.

Comment: Finally: note that the field extension in my first comment is only there because of the general scheme setting.  If you are working at closed points of varieties over an alg. closed field $k$, then $\kappa(x) = \kappa(y) = k$ and you don't need to make any extension of scalars.

Comment: I am working on a algebraic closed field. Sadly, even though I can prove your assertion, I cannot see a morphism between varieties in my question. i guess you want to say there is a morphism from some tangent space to $T_p X$ and hence what?

Comment: I feel sorry for being a "stupid math lover" but could you please give me a draft of the way tackle this problem?

Comment: Of course there's no need to apologize for anything; I'll write a little more my answer (since comments seem to want me to move to chat).

Comment: Since $X$ is a non-singular variety, the dimension of the Zariski tangent space $T_p L$ equals to $dim(L) = 1$. Hence the image of embedding $f_*:T_p L\to T_p X$ is indeed a one-dimensional subspace of $T_p X$. Every $L\in L_p$ defines a one-dimensional subspace of $T_p X$ and hence an element in $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$. $L_p$ defines an closed subset of $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; the one thing that you haven't proved yet (at least in what you've written) is that $L_p$ really is a *closed* subset of $T_pX$.  There are various ways to think about this; if you don't see how to approach it theoretically, it wouldn't necessarily hurt to try to compute an example or two.  One thing that could help is to identity $T_p X$ with an actual, concrete linear subspace of $\mathbb A^n$ (here I am intersecting $X$ with one of the standard open affine charts in $P$, so I can work in $\mathbb A^n$), and then $L_p$ is a certain collection of lines contained in this subspace ...

Comment: ... and you can think about why it has to be Zariski closed.

Comment: I am confused. We want to show $L_p$ defines a _closed_ subset of $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$ not of $T_p X$, so I cannot see the necessarity of identifying $T_p X$ with a subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n$. And I am stilling thinking about how to show it's closed...

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped; I should have said $\mathbb P(T_p X)$.  As for the sense of making my suggested identification, maybe it's not necessary (I didn't think too much about all the various ways one might prove this), but it has the the following benefit: The set $L_p$ is defined as an incidence variety, and so it is closed in the space of lines in $\mathbb P$; but what you want to show is that it is closed in $\mathbb P(T_pX)$.  So relating $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb P(T_p X)$, which my suggestion was in the direction of doing, seems like it would be helpful.  As I said, there may be other, ...

Comment: more direct approaches, which avoid the incidence variety point of view.  But in the end, the Zariski closedness of $L_p$ in $\mathbb P(T_pX)$ has to be derived from the Zariski closedness of $X$ in $\mathbb P$ (since where else will it come from), so you have to find some way to connect the equations cutting out $X$ to the equations cutting out $L_p$ in $\mathbb P(T_pX)$.

Comment: Just to put it more directly: how will you produce a collection of homogeneous equations on $T_p X$ whose zero loci are exactly the lines coming from $L_p$?  You want to take a line in $T_p X$, and ask if it comes from an actual line in $\mathbb P$ passing through $p$ and contained in $X$.  For this, wouldn't it be nice if you could just literally identify a line $L$ in $L_p$ with the image of $T_p L$ in $T_pX$?  Then you would be reduced to finding equations determing whether or not $L$ is in $L_p$ (and this is the incidence variety point of view).  That is what is underlying my suggestion.

Comment: Well, let's consider a simpler case: $X$ is a non-singular hypersurface of dimension $d$ defined by $F\in k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]_d$. Now we know the equations defining $X$. What can I do to connect $P$ with $\mathbb{P}(T_p X)$?